# Storing a graph in a queue with minimum distance between adjacent edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, queue

I need to store edges of a graph in a queue so that the distance between the index of incident edges is as minimum as possible.

Is there any algorithm for this purpose?

Comment: "distance between the index of incident edges" what does this mean? Can you give an example? An index is an integer, and it's not clear what "distance" means between two integers. What's the "index" of an edge?

Comment: @pkpnd, for example, the edge `ab` in a graph is stored in index `5` in our queue and the edge `ac` is stored in index `8`. The distance between them is `3`. The aim is to store edges in a sequence that minimizes this number for all incident edges. : )

Comment: So you don't really need a "queue", you just want an ordering of the edges right?

Comment: @pkpnd Yeah, exactly!

Comment: Do you require the absolute best (minimum) solution, or is an approximation ok?

Comment: @pkpnd It's ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reasonable algorithm that will find a local minimum. Basically you start with some arbitrary ordering, and at each step greedily make a local improvement, until no more improvements are possible.

1. Start with an arbitrary ordering `Q` of the edges. (Maybe some heuristics would help, but I don't think it'll be too important.)
2. Compute the current cost `C` of `Q`, which is the sum of the absolute-difference of indices of incident edges.
3. Repeat the following:

   1. For every (unordered) pair of edges `(edge i, edge j)`:

      - Compute the "new cost" `Cij` which is the cost of the current ordering `Q`, except with edge `i` and `j` switched
   2. Let `C*` be the minimum `Cij` computed above, and let `i*` and `j*` be the corresponding edges that were switched
   3. If `C* < C`:

      - Swap edges `i*` and `j*` in `Q`
      - Update `C := C*`
   4. Otherwise (`C* >= C`), no more local swaps are helpful, and we are at a local minimum.

      - Return the current ordering `Q` with cost `C`

If you have extra computation time to spare, you can run the above with different initial orderings. This will likely lead to different local optima, and you can pick the best one across all runs.